# can not add on add on's

Tags: modeling

im very new to blender and computers. I'm trying to use Hardops addon so i placed the entire file into addons and clicked install addons.Is this right?[image]

Comment: I haven't bought the addon so I can't help much, but the official guide should help you I think: Guide Link

Comment: Can't answer for HardOps, but usually you point at the .zip file, not at the addon folder (and still less at a random script like in your screenshot)